# Função js rodar em determinado horario

Tags: javascript, html

Senhores, tenho uma duvida, existe algum método que por exemplo executa em determinado horario?

Eu gostaria de quando fosse 0h a pagina se atualizasse automaticamente, então salvaria algum cookie para informa que aquele dia já foi atualizado..

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo não, vai funcionar apenas uma vez. Para funcionar mais de uma vez, utilize [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) ao invés de [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeOut).

Comment: @Renan acho que nem um dos dois pois o horario tem que ser 0hs e do jeito que coloquei vai ser executado após 24 hs do acesso a página. Concordas?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo não sei, pois você removeu o código. Porém a diferença entre os métodos é que um executa a função informada apenas uma única vez, enquanto o outro repete a execução a cada passagem do intervalo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não acho que seja possível montar e persistir um cookie apenas com HTML e Javascript puros.

A solução mais raiz para fazer algo todo dia à meia noite, apenas com Javascript, seria algo do tipo:

```
var dezSegundos = 10000; // dez segundos em milissegundos
var quinzeSegundos = 15000;
var verificaHora() {
    var agora = new Date();
    var hoje = new Date(agora.getFullYear(), agora.getMonth(), agora.GetDate());
    var msDesdeMeiaNoite = agora.getTime() - hoje.getTime();
    if (msDesdeMeiaNoite < quinzeSegundos) {
        // Aqui você executa sua lógica
    } 
}
setInterval(verificaHora, dezSegundos);
```

Explicação: o código roda de cinco em cinco minutos - utilize [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) ao invés de [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) para que o código continue executando por vários dias seguidos. Então, se for a primeira vez que ele roda em um dia, ele faz alguma coisa que você tenha implementado.

Pra completar, como o setInterval [não tem garantias de executar exatamente no instante para o qual foi programado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified), nós damos uma folga de cinco segundos para ele executar.

Comment: E se eu dar um reload na pagina da problema no fluxo dos intervalos? E ele executara uma vez sempre meia noite ou na primeira vez do dia?

Comment: Se você recarregar a página, você perde as threads que estavam rodando. Se for fazer com recarga então tanto faz o `setTimeout` quanto o `setInterval`. O problema com isso é que se a recarga demorar demais você pode acabar perdendo a hora. Vale a pena tentar todas as alternativas sugeridas por aqui e ver qual resolve melhor o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Essa função aqui funciona perfeitamente para isso, só mudar para os horários desejados e usar a função `reload()` para atualizar a página.

```
var now = new Date();
var millisTill10 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 10, 0, 0, 0) - now;
if (millisTill10 < 0) {
     millisTill10 += 86400000; // já passou das 10 da manhã, começa de novo.
}
setTimeout(function(){alert("São 10 da manhã!")}, millisTill10);
```

Answer (score 0):

a linguagem não da esse tipo de liberdade ate pelo fato de ser bem rara a utilização, o que você pode fazer é pegar a hora:minuto:segundo no momento que a pagina é carregada, calcular quantos ms faltam para o próximo dia e colocar o que deseja dentro de um setTimeOut.

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz assim

```js
setInterval(function () {
  var agora = new Date();
  var a = `${agora}`;
  var resultado = a.split(" ");
  console.log(resultado[4]);
  if (resultado[4] == '00:00:00') {
    console.log('aqui fica sua função');
  }
}, 1000);
```